# svelte resolve if statement during animation

Tags: svelte

I have some svelte code that simplified looks like this

```
{#if conditional}
<ContentA/>
{:else}
<ContentB/>
<Drawer transition:fly>
   <Compontent />
</Drawer>
{/if}
```

in most situations this works fine.
But if the component modifies the conditional in some way then I am getting a behavior that I am not too fond of. Since the component has a fade out it will show `ContentB` until the animation is done, and only after that will it switch to `ContentA`.

Is there any way of getting this working with both an animation and an instant switch of content?

Comment: https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key

Comment: @possum interesting doc, but I don't see how that helps me.
are you saying wrap the if statement in a key block?